# How to compare values of two columns and return true or false based whether they match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of order numbers ColA, and a list of order numbers of people who have responded to an email, ColB.
I want to be able to compare these so I can resend a new email to those that have not yet responded, so I simply need a true false based upon whether a number from col B exists anywhere in colA, or vice versa really.
I have tried so many things and nothing seems to work.
What seems like it should work is:

`=IF(A1=B:B, "", A1)`

I've also tried other things but it seem that google sheets code wont work properly. For example the internet states

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$1001,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)`

should create a true false based upon colA and colB but all I get is endless false statements.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome. A question structured like this could be answered like: *use a formula*  Please [edit] your question according to [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In any case give a thought to the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) function. Do let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

### Get non responded order ID's

> **Try this**, no need for TRUE / FALSE column

```
=iferror(filter(A2:B, iserror(match(A2:A,D2:D, false))), "no match")
```

> Green - ID's responded
> Red   - ID's Not responded

[image]

> Associate the emails with the id's with `Vlookup` in cell `E2`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="",,VLOOKUP(D2:D,$A$2:$B,2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. can I ask what you are using to continue to associate the emails with the id's? What is the formula in H?

Comment: @Stephen I updated the answer take a look `=ArrayFormula(IF(G2:G="",,VLOOKUP(G2:G,$A$2:$B,2,0)))`

Comment: @Osm you dont need fx in H column if you change A2:A to A2:B - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTrOM.png

Comment: Yeh well spotted thanks, this skips 
2 steps., I copied the formula from `I2` to `H2` out of laziness.

Comment: As @player0 noted, expanding the filter range to include the whole table makes the solution straightforward , _check the answer edits if you have a different use case_